# Reference only works after doubleclicking cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to input references via a Script. The script changes the name of a sheet and then procedds to add some references to a "coversheet". However one of the references states error first until you doubleclick the cell once. I have no idea why. The reference itself obviously works, its just that i need to doubleclick once for it to function properly. here is the code(flush was a try to fix it, but had no effect):

```
     sheet.setName(newName);
     sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(newName);
     var link2 = "=HYPERLINK(\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/edit#gid=" + sheetID + "\";" + "\"" + newName + "\")";
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 2).setValue("='" + newName + "'!N28");
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 3).setValue(link2);
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 4).setValue("='" + newName + "'!B3");
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 5).setValue("='" + newName + "'!H1");
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 6).setValue("='" + newName + "'!N1");
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 8).setValue("='" + newName + "'!F1");
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     overview.getRange(rowIndex, 7).setValue("=ArrayFormula(concatenate('" + newName + "'!M11:M13&\";\")"); //Wanted =ArrayFormula(concatenate(NameA1:A10&",")) 
     overview.sort(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a closer look it turns out you forgot to close concatenate's parentheses which led to the error that was automatically corrected on double click:

```
overview.getRange(rowIndex, 7).setValue("=ArrayFormula(concatenate(" + newName + "!M11:M13&\";\"))");
```

should work